# not getting proper data from adapter to next activity

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am new to Android. I am developing an application in which I have a list of employees. The List view contins a text view i.e employee name and three image views i.e on click of one image view i have to delete that employee from database and on click of another image i have to edit details for which i have another activity. on click of this edit image i want to start new activity and pass the details of the corresponding employee using intent which will be shown in edittext. But this not working properly. If i click on delete image of first employee, some other employee gets deleted. and when passing data to EditActivity data is also not proper.

Please help me. How to do this?

In my MainActivity I am getting data from server in JSONArray format and i am  displaying the data in list view. I dont understand why I am not getting proper data. Do I have something wrong in MainActivity or in Adapter..

This is my adapter

```
public class EmployeesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    TextView categoryName;
    Pojo pojo;
    private Context activity1;
    ArrayList<Pojo> data1;
    private ArrayList<Pojo> arraylist1 = null;
    public static LayoutInflater inflater;
    ImageView edit, delete, historyy;
    String del_empid;

    public EmployeesAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<Pojo> employee1) {
         activity1 = ctx;
         data1 = employee1;
         inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity1
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         this.arraylist1 = new ArrayList<Pojo>();
         this.arraylist1.addAll(data1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
       return data1.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data1.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         View v = convertView;
         v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.manage_emp_list, parent, false);
         pojo = data1.get(position);
         categoryName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.employeeName);
         categoryName.setText(pojo.getMgEmpName());
         edit = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgedit);
         delete = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgdelete);
         historyy = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgHistory);
         final int pos = position;
    edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Pojo domain = data1.get(pos);
            String emp_name = domain.getMgEmpName();
            String emp_contact = domain.getMgEmpContact();
            String emp_email = domain.getMgEmpEmail();
            String emp_appcost = domain.getMgEmpAppCost();
            Intent i = new Intent(activity1, EditEmployee.class);
            i.putExtra("empname", emp_name);
            i.putExtra("empmobile", emp_contact);
            i.putExtra("empemail", emp_email);
            i.putExtra("empappcost", emp_appcost);
            activity1.startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            del_empid = data1.get(position).getMgEmp_id();
            new NetCheck().execute();
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

This is Mainactivity where i am getting data from server which i am displaying it in listview. Here i am displaying only employee name with three images in the list item. But i have multiple data for each item in list view. I am using setter and getter functions. Also I want to show previous data before loading from server therfore i Have used SharedPreferences . Am I doing anything wrong in this MainActivty that's why I am getting such type of problem in the adpter?

```
 public class EmployeesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Pojo pojo;
String strServerResponse = null;
ArrayList<Pojo> employee1;
EmployeesAdapter mainAdapter;
String tipsss;
ArrayList<String> tii;
ListView mainList;
String emplid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_employees);
    mainList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.manageemployeeList);
    employee1 = new ArrayList<Pojo>();
    tii = new ArrayList<String>();
    new NetCheck().execute();
};


private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPref4", MODE_PRIVATE);

        Pojo pojo;
        Set<String> names = prefs.getStringSet("employeename", null);
        Set<String> ids = prefs.getStringSet("employeeid", null);
        Set<String> mobiles = prefs.getStringSet("employeemobile", null);
        Set<String> emails = prefs.getStringSet("employeeemail", null);
        Set<String> appcosts = prefs.getStringSet("employeeappcost", null);

        List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>(0);
        nameList.addAll(names);
        List<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>(0);
        idList.addAll(ids);
        List<String> mobileList = new ArrayList<String>(0);
        mobileList.addAll(mobiles);
        List<String> emailidList = new ArrayList<String>(0);
        emailidList.addAll(emails);
        List<String> appcostidList = new ArrayList<String>(0);
        appcostidList.addAll(appcosts);
        employee1.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
            pojo = new Pojo();
            pojo.setMgEmpName(nameList.get(i));
            pojo.setMgEmp_id(idList.get(i));
            pojo.setMgEmpContact(mobileList.get(i));
            pojo.setMgEmpEmail(emailidList.get(i));
            pojo.setMgEmpAppCost(appcostidList.get(i));
            employee1.add(pojo);
        }
        mainAdapter = new EmployeesAdapter(EmployeesActivity.this, employee1);
        mainList.setAdapter(mainAdapter);

        return;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            SharedPreferences preff = getSharedPreferences(
                    "MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
            String id = preff.getString("id", null);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(
                    "http://url");
            httpRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("employer_id", id);
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
            se.setContentType("application/json");
            httpRequest.setEntity(se);
            HttpResponse httpRes = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);

            java.io.InputStream inputStream = httpRes.getEntity()
                    .getContent();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            inputStream.close();
            strServerResponse = sb.toString();

            if (strServerResponse != null) {
                try {

                    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
                    JSONObject jsonObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
                    ArrayList<String> tii = new ArrayList<String>();
                    ArrayList<String> tii2 = new ArrayList<String>();
                    ArrayList<String> tii3 = new ArrayList<String>();
                    ArrayList<String> tii4 = new ArrayList<String>();
                    ArrayList<String> tii5 = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                        pojo = new Pojo();
                        JSONObject jobj2 = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                        String empname = jobj2.optString("name");
                        String empid = jobj2.optString("id");
                        String empmobile = jobj2.optString("mobile");
                        String empemail = jobj2.optString("email");
                        String empappcost = jobj2.optString("app_cost");
                        tii.add(empname);
                        tii2.add(empid);
                        tii3.add(empmobile);
                        tii4.add(empemail);
                        tii5.add(empappcost);
                    }

                    List<String> listTemp = tii;
                    List<String> listTemp1 = tii2;
                    List<String> listTemp2 = tii3;
                    List<String> listTemp3 = tii4;
                    List<String> listTemp4 = tii5;

                    Set<String> temp = new HashSet<String>(listTemp);
                    Set<String> temp2 = new HashSet<String>(listTemp1);
                    Set<String> temp3 = new HashSet<String>(listTemp2);
                    Set<String> temp4 = new HashSet<String>(listTemp3);
                    Set<String> temp5 = new HashSet<String>(listTemp4);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyPref4", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    temp.addAll(listTemp);
                    temp2.addAll(listTemp1);
                    temp3.addAll(listTemp2);
                    temp4.addAll(listTemp3);
                    temp5.addAll(listTemp4);
                    editor.putStringSet("employeename", temp);
                    editor.putStringSet("employeeid", temp2);
                    editor.putStringSet("employeemobile", temp3);
                    editor.putStringSet("employeeemail", temp4);
                    editor.putStringSet("employeeappcost", temp5);
                    editor.commit();

                }
```

this is my Pojo class where i have setter and getter functions for employee details.

```
  public class Pojo {
       private String mg_empName;
       private String mg_empEmail;
       private String mg_empContact;

       public void setMgEmpContact(String mg_empContact) {
            this.mg_empContact = mg_empContact;
       }

       public String getMgEmpContact() {
            return mg_empContact;
       }

       public void setMgEmpEmail(String mg_empEmail) {
            this.mg_empEmail = mg_empEmail;
       }

       public String getMgEmpEmail() {
            return mg_empEmail;
       }

       public void setMgEmpName(String mg_empName) {
             this.mg_empName = mg_empName;
       }

       public String getMgEmpName() {
            return mg_empName;
       }

  }
```

Can anyone please help me. Why am I getting such type of problem? Is anything wrong here? The way i have used Arraylist and then setting the data in postExecute() method is correct?......

Answer (score 0):

Use this code ...

```
 final int pos = position;
    edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
Pojo domain = data1.get(pos);
                String emp_name = domain.getMgEmpName();
                String emp_contact = domain.getMgEmpContact();
                String emp_email = domain.getMgEmpEmail();
                String emp_appcost = domain.getMgEmpAppCost();
                Intent i = new Intent(activity1, EditEmployee.class);
                i.putExtra("empname", emp_name);
                i.putExtra("empmobile", emp_contact);
                i.putExtra("empemail", emp_email);
                i.putExtra("empappcost", emp_appcost);
                activity1.startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

It works perfect.

Comment: what r u getting in onclick can u say it

Comment: I have added MainActivity.. can u please check

Comment: Change `setOnClickListener`to `onItemClickListener` something like this `edit.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.onItemClickListener() `

Comment: @Firefog it is an imageview not listview to use onitemclicklistener

Comment: @NarendraKumar Am I doing anything wrong in MainActivity. Please help me

Comment: can u post Pojo class and list_item.xml and manifest file. so that i can check and clarify u

Comment: @NarendraKumar I have added Pojo class and updated adapter class

Comment: @NarendraKumar Question doesnot accept so much of code so i cannot add other files

Answer (score 0):

instead of initializing `pojo = data1.get(position);` make local varibale as `final Pojo pojo = data1.get(position); inside the getView()`
because in your case the pojo field is retinitialized as the getview is called all rows to be visible

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
  this.arraylist1 = employee1;
```